# I can't install packages due to an OSE error: Errno 2 No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, sfml

I'm relatively new to coding. I'm using Python 3.11.2 in PyCharm 2022.3.3. One day, when I tried to use `pip` to install the sfml package using the command `pip install sfml`, I encountered this error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSE error:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_2mfz521\output.json'
```

Python is installed in the folder `D:\Programy\Python311`, and PyCharm is installed in the folder `D:\Programy\PyCharmCommunity`.

What should I do? Please help.

```
pip install sfml Collecting sfml
Using cached sfml-2.3.2.dev1.tar.gz (506 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Downloading build dependencies ... done
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSE error:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_2mfz521\output.json
```

The same thing happens in both PowerShell and CMD console.

I have updated everything, disabled the Windows Defender firewall, deleted all temporary files from the temporary folder (including enabling support for long Windows system paths), but the error still persists.

Comment: Are you using a command window that was started with administrator privileges?

Comment: Yes, always use